# error while convert from int32 to string

Tags: c#, string

This is my code :

```
bool Wert;
Int32 Zahl1 = 7;
Int32 Zahl2 = 4;
Int32 Rechnung = Zahl1 + Zahl2;
Console.WriteLine("Rechnung =");
Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(Zahl1, Zahl2));
Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die Lösung ein");
Int32 Ergebniss = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (Rechnung== Ergebniss)
  {
     Wert = true;
     if (Wert == true)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("Richtig");
     }

  }
else
  {
    Wert = false;
    if (Wert == false)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Falsch");
    }
 }

 Console.ReadLine();
```

And i get this error :
CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

How can i fix this ?
Im realy new to programming and trying to lern it. Sorry for bad english

Comment: First of all don't be declaring your ints as `Int32`. Just use `int`.

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? You've given 28 lines of code but not said where the issue is. I would say that it's not at all clear what you expect `Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(Zahl1, Zahl2));
` to do... what were you trying to achieve there?

Comment: There's no overload of `Console.WriteLine` that takes two integers (which is what the immediate issue is). It's not clear what you want to write, so it's tricky to suggest how to resolve. It also doesn't return anything, so it's not clear why you're trying to convert whatever you think it returns to an integer either.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is from the line

`Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(Zahl1, Zahl2));`

What is this line supposed to be doing?
 Because the variables `Zahl1` and `Zahl2` are both integers, but the function `Console.WriteLine()` is supposed to be passed a string, not a pair of integers. (This is what is causing your error I think).

ALso, the `WriteLine()` method returns `void` So you are not passing anything into the `ConvertToInt32()` method to be converted.

Comment: Convert what to Int32 ?? The `WriteLine()` method is void, it does not return anything to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure exactly what Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(Zahl1, Zahl2)); is supposed to do.  Did you want the answer to be 74 or 11?

```
Int32 Zahl1 = 7;
Int32 Zahl2 = 4;
Int32 Rechnung = Zahl1 + Zahl2;
Console.WriteLine("Rechnung = {0}", Rechnung);

// If you want the answer to be 74
Int32 losung = Convert.ToInt32(Zahl1 + Zahl2);

// If you want the answer to be 11
Int32 losung = Rechnung;

Console.WriteLine("Geben sie die Lösung ein {0}", losung);
Int32 Ergebniss = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (Rechnung == Ergebniss)
    Console.WriteLine("Richtig");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Falsch");
Console.ReadLine();
```